# PHP with two FOR loops

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have two "for" loops

First for is to get year range between 1990 and 2019, and the for inside it have to run my script five times with the same year. Example

```
for($i=1990;$i<2019,$i++){
 for($j=1;$j<5;$j++){
    $film = "API";
        $sve = file_get_contents($film);

        $data = json_decode($sve);

        foreach($data->results as $key => $value){
            $filmovi .= $value->title . ",";
        }
}
```

So, it must run five times in one year, like

1990 - 1,2,3,4,5

1991 - 1,2,3,4,5 etc etc..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you getting the contents of the same file every time through the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it, will only run 4 times for each year and exclude 2019.
Change your limits on the for loops:

```
for($i=1990;$i<=2019,$i++){
  $filmovi = "";
  for($j=1;$j<=5;$j++){
        $film = "API";
        $sve = file_get_contents($film);

        $data = json_decode($sve);

        foreach($data->results as $key => $value){
            $filmovi .= $value->title . ",";
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am fetching from API something, and the first year (1990) have 100lines, 1991 should have 100 lines too but it has 200(lines from 1990 are added), third has 400(1990 and 1991)..

that is the main problem

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev Sounds like you need to set `$filmovi` back to `""` at the beginning of each year.

Comment: If that's the problem you're having then I'd say @Barmar is right. I updated my answer to correct that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner if you avoid traditional for-loops:

```
<?php

foreach (range(1990, 2019) as $year) {
   $count = 0;
   while($count++ <5) {
      print("$year $count\n");
      // do your thing here
   }
}
```

Comment: How is that any better?